# X-XSS-Protection vs CSP

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy

As far as I understand, CSP can be used for all the same things as `X-XSS-Protection` and more. If you are using CSP, is there any good reason to use `X-XSS-Protection` as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> is there any good reason to use X-XSS-Protection as well?

[With some doubts](http://blog.innerht.ml/the-misunderstood-x-xss-protection/) (see Kevin's comment below) the answer is probably yes.

`X-Xss-Protection` activates a heuristic, reflected xss detection feature. Reflected xss comes in the form of parameters, which makes it easy to determine the scope of the potential attack.

Browsers execute HTML. By definition browsers cannot provide any guarantees about data safety of server generated HTML code. It is impossible to determine trusted vs malicious javascript... unless you use CSP. CSP allows you to **choose** what javascript the browser executes.

An enforced CSP that does not allow inline javascript, eval, or 3rd party sources is pretty solid and `x-xss-protection` would provide little benefit to most of your users.

**If your users' browsers support CSP that is.**

`x-xss-protection` has been supported by IE for many years. So in the case that someone is using IE < 12, CSP is useless where `x-xss-protection` can help.

> So, yes. Both. Always. The internet would be a much safer world if every website deployed both.

[Consensus has changed since this was originally written](https://owasp.org/www-project-secure-headers/#x-xss-protection). It is now advised to explicitly disable the feature with `X-Xss-Protection: 0`.

I haven't dug in too far, but I haven't found a site that uses CSP but not `x-xss-protection`

```
for i in twitter.com vine.co github.com
do
   echo "$i"
   curl -Is "https://$i" | grep -iE "(x-xss-protection|content-security-policy)"
done
```

Comment: Firefox does no support reflected-xss (tested with 47.0.1) either. Chrome support it but does not support sending the violation to report-uri. So at this point there are no benefit for using CSP for reflected-xss.

Comment: As a counterpoint, this article highlights some issues with the implementation of X-XSS-Protection and mentions that Fb actually had to explicitly disable it by using `X-XSS-Protection: 0` due to exploits. http://blog.innerht.ml/the-misunderstood-x-xss-protection/ Whether it is beneficial or not for your site ultimately depends on the little details. You can consider tweaking your answer if you find this point worth considering.

Comment: I've changed the wording slightly and referenced your link

Answer (score 0):

**Content Security Policy**

The content security policy (CSP) is an additional layer of security added by some compatible browsers. With proper configuration, CSP helps to mitigate certain attacks such as XSS and script injection attacks or packet sniffing attacks.
Technically, CSP is enabled if the header Content-Security-Policy is provided by the backend. Alternatively, It also can be enabled by the frontend. it is done by using the element  as follows:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; img-src https://*; child-src 'none';">`

CSP helps to stop XSS by whitelisting the executed javascript sources which also includes inline script and event-handling HTML attributes. The whitelisting is configured by the administator. The Admin can decides whether all the javascript links lead to the same origin, specific domain and what types of medias to expect from each domain. configuration examples:

Same Origin: `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'`

Explicit Trusted domain: `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' *.trusted.com`

**X-XSS-PROTECTION**

The goal of this header is to block XSS in the loaded page. The Admin got minimal configuration options such as reporting url, blocking page from loading...
With proper CSP configuration, this header is not very effective. specially in modern browsers.